# DI Castle WCF constructor How Do I

Tags: c#, oop, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

I have inherited a project using Castle DI.  I am adding a WCF to the solution and need to use some of the functions in the solution.  The class has the following, which I am assuming is injection.

```
private readonly IOrderRepository _orderRepository;
    private readonly IEshopOrderRepository _eShopOrderRepository;
    private readonly IUserRepository _userRepository;
    private readonly IListRepository _listRepository;
    private readonly INHibernateRepositoryWithTypedId<ProductVariant, string> _productVariantRepository;

    private readonly IMapper<GiftCardPayment, string, GiftCardPaymentDto> _giftCardDtoMapper;
    private readonly IMapper<AbstractOrder, OrderDto> _orderDtoMapper;
    private readonly IMapper<AbstractOrder, RecurringOrder> _recurringOrder;
    private readonly IMapper<Address, CreditCardPaymentDto> _creditCardDtoMapper;

    public delegate OrderDto ShipmentProcessing(OrderDto order, bool isRecap);

    public OrderManagementService(IOrderRepository orderRepository, IUserRepository userRepository, IListRepository listRepository,
        IEshopOrderRepository eShopOrderRepository,
        INHibernateRepositoryWithTypedId<ProductVariant, string> productVariantRepository,
        IMapper<GiftCardPayment, string, GiftCardPaymentDto> giftCardDtoMapper,
                                  IMapper<AbstractOrder, OrderDto> orderDtoMapper,
        IMapper<AbstractOrder, RecurringOrder> recurringOrder,
        IMapper<Address, CreditCardPaymentDto> creditCardDtoMapper)
    {
        _orderRepository = orderRepository;
        _eShopOrderRepository = eShopOrderRepository;
        _userRepository = userRepository;
        _listRepository = listRepository;
        _productVariantRepository = productVariantRepository;
        _giftCardDtoMapper = giftCardDtoMapper;
        _orderDtoMapper = orderDtoMapper;
        _recurringOrder = recurringOrder;
        _creditCardDtoMapper = creditCardDtoMapper;
    }
```

All of which works.  My question is how do I implement this pattern in the WCF service class.  I cannot add the parameters to the constructor because the client will not supply them.

I am able to use the DI in the WCF, so that part is working.

Thanks

Comment: That's a lot of dependencies you've got there. You might want to refactor that class. Take a look [here](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/01/20/RebuttalConstructorOverinjectionAntipattern.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Castle has a [WCF facility](http://docs.castleproject.org/Default.aspx?Page=WCF-Facility-Registration&NS=Windsor&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) for that. In essence it is a custom service factory that creates your service instead of the default factory WCF provides. If you want to use the fluent registration, you have to supply your services to the container used in the service host factory. For that you can create your own service host factory inheriting from the one the castle project provides (Castle.Facilities.WcfIntegration.DefaultServiceHostFactory) and create the windsor container in the factories' constructor.

an example implementation for your own service host factory, derived from the DefaultServiceHostFactory supplied by castle:

```
public class MyOwnServiceHostFactory: Castle.Facilities.WcfIntegration.DefaultServiceHostFactory
{

    public MyOwnServiceHostFactory() : base(CreateKernel())
    { }

    private static Castle.MicroKernel.IKernel CreateKernel()
    {
        var container = new Castle.Windsor.WindsorContainer();
        container.Install(new WindsorInstaller());
        return container.Kernel;
    }

}


public class WindsorInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{

    #region IWindsorInstaller Members

    public void Install(Castle.Windsor.IWindsorContainer container, Castle.MicroKernel.SubSystems.Configuration.IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.AddFacility<Castle.Facilities.WcfIntegration.WcfFacility>();
        container.AddFacility<Castle.Facilities.TypedFactory.TypedFactoryFacility>();

        container.Kernel.Resolver.AddSubResolver(new Castle.MicroKernel.Resolvers.SpecializedResolvers.ListResolver(container.Kernel));
        // add your services here...
    }

}
```

Comment: So I used NuGet to install castle wcf facility.  I had to remove the old version from all 8 projects and install the new version.  I now have a load of errors similar to The type 'Castle.MicroKernel.Registration.Component' exists in both Castle.Windsor.dll and Castle.MicroKernel.dll.  -  any idaes on what would be causing these types of errors?

Comment: can't check right now, but i assume you have using statements for both Castle.Windsor and Castle.MicroKernel and both contain a class "Component". If you now register your services with Component.For<>, the compiler doesn't know which one to take. You can either use the full name of the class including the namespace (Castle.MicroKernel.Component) or remove the reference to the Castle.Windsor-Namespace.

Comment: i added a code example for the service host factory and the container configuration...